# Hostname validation; new gTLD & store email addresses

Tags: email, validation

#### **UPDATE**: While I got the answer I needed down below, this question was later asked again in [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54543/invalid-email-address-admineternal-florist) and received a more [elaborate answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/54613/13191).

My magento store is hosted on a 'new' gTLD (.boutique), but Magento does not allow me to set the store email addresses with this tld.

I understand that Magento's validation runs through the Zend framework and the responsible file for validating the TLDs is '`Hostname.php`' in `/lib/Zend/Validate/`.
However, adding all the TLDs from http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt as suggested in [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/1039603/#t483550) thread on the Magento forums did not solve my problem.

I thought perhaps it was an issue with Magento storing the previous Zend file in a cache, so I already tried clearing all cache files from the cache management page; this did not resolve the problem.

Am I overlooking any other arrays or such that should include all the TLDs? Should I clear the cache in another way? Anything else altogether?

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: I was naughty and actually edited the Zend file in `/lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php` after making a `Hostname.php.bak` file in the same dir. Moving the edited `Hostname.php` file to `/app/code/local/Zend/Validate/` and restoring the original `Hostname.php.bak` in the Zend library as suggested by the marked answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this and it worked perfectly. What did you do exactly? My steps are:

1. Copy ./lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php to ./app/code/**local**/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php.
2. Added ", 'test'" to the $_validTlds array on line 136.
3. Tried to save the store e-mail address with a .test domain and it worked.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. I added what I did wrong as an edit in the original question. Still somewhat curious why my method wouldn't work though..