# how to adjust Magento 1.9.0.1 to accept an unsusual emaildomain for a customer's email?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, customer-account

I want to add a new customer to our Magento 1.9.0.1 store, but am rejected to save it due to the email domain of that customer's email address info@[domain].zone. I couldn't reproduce the problem in a 1.9.1.0 teststore we are having, so it may be a sepcific 1.9.0.1 issue

I can't post the exact error message but it seems Magento doesn't know about the .zone domain and I was wondering where I can add it to something like "acceptable mail domains" in the magento backend?

disclaimer: I'm fairly new to Magento and likewise may miss some of the basics  yet. Sorry if I may use incorrect terms (which is also due to little experience)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid email address "admin@eternal.florist"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54543/invalid-email-address-admineternal-florist) Check also answer from here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48309/hostname-validation-new-gtld-store-email-addresses?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: yes, true. That post is pretty much the same issue from another angle. Sorry I didn't see this before & thanks @sv3n for pointing that out.

Comment: NP :) Guess 2nd link will solve you problem, if not please make an edit to your question to reopen it.